# MongoDB Query with sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple document setup:

```
{
    VG: "East",
    Artikellist: {
        Artikel1: "Sprite",
        Amount1: 1,
        Artikel2: "Fanta",
        Amount2: 3
    }
}
```

actually i just want to query these document to get a list of selling articels in each VG, or maybe town, doesnt matter. In addition the Query should sum the Amount of each product and give it back to me.

I Know i'm thinking in a SQL language, but that's actually the case.

May idea was this on here:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            VG: "$VG",
            Artikel1: "$Artikellist.Artikel1",
            Artikel2: "$Artikellist.Artikel2",
            $sum: "$Artikellist.Amount1",
            $sum: "$Artikellist.Amount2"
        },
    }
}]);
```

The hardest point here that i have 5 different values for VG and and it could be maximum of 5 Artikel and regarding amounts in one list.

So Hopefully you can help me here. Sry for my bad english and for my badder Mongo Skills.

Comment: $Sum and the likes will only work on fields with same names. You should have objects like {"artikel":"name","amount":"20"} in an array or collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Artikel1 is always "Sprite" and Artikel2 - "Fanta", then you can try this one:

```
db.test.aggregate({$group : {  _id : {VG : "$VG", Artikel1 : "$Artikellist.Artikel1", Artikel2 : "$Artikellist.Artikel2"}, Amount1 : {$sum : "$Artikellist.Amount1"},Amount2 : {$sum : "$Artikellist.Amount2"}}});
```

If values of Artikel1 and Artikel2 can vary I suggest changing the structure of document say to:

```
{
VG: "East",
Artikellist: [
    { Artikel: "Sprite",
      Amount: 1},
    { Artikel: "Fanta",
    Amount: 3 }
]}
```

and then use the following approach:

```
db.test.aggregate({$unwind : "$Artikellist"}, {$group : {_id : {VG : "$VG", Artikel : "$Artikellist.Artikel"}, Amount : {$sum : "$Artikellist.Amount"}}})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Works as expected :)